# Body onLoad Click to refresh iframe

Tags: javascript, html, iframe, click, onload

I have an iframe with a button in it that I'd like to click on page load. 
The iframe is:

```
    `<iframe id="rf" onload="myFunction()" style="width: 100%; height: 600px;" src="http://clients.mindbodyonline.com/ws.asp?studioid=103099&amp;stype=-7&amp;sTG=22&amp;sView=day" width="320" height="240" frameborder="0" scrolling="auto"></iframe>`
```

I've added this javascript underneath it to click the button on page load, but it's not working. "tabA7" is the button id.

```
    `<script>
    function myFunction{
    document.getElementById("tabA7").click(); 
    }
    </script>`
```

Comment: you want to trigger the click function after the iframe has loaded

Comment: Is the script tag in the iframe or its parent doc?

Answer (score 0):

There's nothing wrong with your code (see snippet for your code in action).  The only reason it may not be executing the click event is because there's no element with ID tabA7.

```js
function myFunction() {
  document.getElementById('theButton').click();
}

function button() {
  alert('button clicked');
}
```

```html
<iframe id="rf" onload="myFunction()" style="width: 100%; height: 600px;" src="http://clients.mindbodyonline.com/ws.asp?studioid=103099&amp;stype=-7&amp;sTG=22&amp;sView=day" width="320" height="240" frameborder="0" scrolling="auto"></iframe>
<br/>
<button id="theButton" onclick="button()">button</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use the frame's `contentDocument` property:

```
document.getElementById('myFrame').contentDocument.getElementById('myButton')
```

However, the browser will probably block that access unless protocol, domain, and port from both URLs match. Also make sure you wait until the frame is loaded before trying to access its contents.